# Protect custom properties in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

We have several templates in Word2016 which uses custom variables, these variables should be updated with my macro, so that data gets pushed to the Database when the user changes them.

Unfortunately we have some users that deletes the variables in the documents(in the text not in the file properties) which means that the database does not get updated. Is there a setting to make custom properties not able to be deleted from the text?

Properties for one example document are listed below
[image]

This is how it should look like in the document
[image]

Then this is what happens sometimes, which should not be allowed
[image]

By doing so I do not need to loop through document to find variables, because I can simply loop through custom properties:

```
Public Sub initializeVariablesFromDB(doc As Document, dokID As String)
    Dim docProp As Object
    Dim rowNumber As Integer

    'Get valid properties
    If CPearson.IsArrayEmpty(Settings.validPropertiesArray) Then
        Settings.validPropertiesArray = Post.helpRequest("xxxxxx?Dok2=1")
    End If

    'We create the docid just in case....
    Call CustomProperties.createCustomDocumentProperty(doc, "_DocumentID", dokID)

    'We loop through all custom properties
    For Each docProp In doc.CustomDocumentProperties
        rowNumber = CPearson.findRownumber(docProp.name, Settings.validPropertiesArray)
        If rowNumber <> -1 Then
            'we clear all SIGN properties...
            If InStr(UCase(docProp.name), "SIGN") > 0 Then
                docProp.value = ""
            End If

            'We check if we should use value from DB
            If Settings.validPropertiesArray(rowNumber, 1) = "0" Or InStr(UCase(docProp.name), "DOCUMENTCREATEDDATE") > 0 _
                Or InStr(UCase(docProp.name), "DOCUMENTCREATOR") > 0 Or InStr(UCase(docProp.name), "DOCUMENTNAME") > 0 Then

                'Update from DB
                Call Post.updateDBFromCustomProperties(docId:=dokID, PropertyName:=docProp.name, whoRules:="dBrules", doc:=doc)

            End If
        End If
    Next docProp
End Sub
```

This will fail for the _DocumentSubject in the text, the new value to the property will be collected but is not reflected in the text anymore because the user deleted the variable in the text, can I prevent this?

Comment: Can you update your question with the Microsoft Word version you use? For Version 2007 and upwards you could protect them with "Content Controls" (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/About-content-controls-283b1e29-0b77-4781-b236-2d02c1cce1c2)

Answer (score 1):

You can put the field into a Content Control and lock the content control. Users who know enough about MS Word can still delete the content control but they would need to take some fairly deliberate steps to do so *(and I'm guessing those people are not the problem)*.

---

Normal fields, including document properties, can be added to content controls (probably best to use *rich text*).

> You can put the field into a Content Control, seems like you can not do that :( – skatun 10 hours ago

***You can totally do it***, follow these steps (*Word 2010*):

1. Add a custom property to a new blank (even unsaved) document _SlowLearner
2. Add a *RichText* content control from the *DeveloperTab*
3. Click inside the content control
4. Insert > Quick Parts > Field
5. Filter fields *Document Information* > select *DocProperty*
6. Select property: _SlowLearner > OK

**Note:** the field is protected when the Content Control is fully locked. This has the curious side effect that the Content Control does NOT allow the field to update normally... to get around this you need to add some more code to your VBA, like this:

```
Sub UpdateProtectedField()
    With ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1)
        .LockContents = False
        .Range.Fields(1).Update
        .LockContents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: Custom Document Property] [image: Content Control Properties] [image: Insert Field Dialogue] [image: Field Protected in Content Control]

Comment: You can put the field into a Content Control, seems like you can not do that :(

Comment: @skatun any luck with this??

Comment: I am thinking about it, how i can add it on the flow when i update the custom properties, or if it should only be implemented for new documents, or if I should convert to use Content control instead of CustomProperties. My idea currently is when I do check the text for customvariables, that I then at same time wrap it inside the rich text Content control

Comment: In my templates I use a combination of Custom XML - to which the content control can be mapped, and custom property fields in content controls.  I prefer the Custom XML approach but that's quite different to what you currently have. I think your current idea to retrospectively wrap variables in content controls is workable - I'd suggest closing out this question and opening a new question if required.  Cheers

Comment: I hope to get around to it tomorrow and upload some example code of how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use continuous sections breaks and protect sections, not an ideal solution because then images can not be formatted and so on..